# BatchMessageListenerContainer using DMLC and Spring-batch

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-batch

I am trying to setup a DMLC so that it picks up a certain amount of messages from a JMS broker (ActiveMQ) within the same transaction and should any error occur, the transaction is rolled back so that all message contained within that transaction end up in DLQ, or better yet, do not leave the broker.

I found an implementation for a BatchMessageListenerContainer using spring-batch under the spring-batch-infrastucture-tests repo (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-infrastructure-tests) however the tests don't really do anything with the message.

Ideally I'd like to adapt so that the messages received in the message listener would somehow be bound to the RepeatContext so that actions done by repeatOperations can be performed on the messages too however the issue is that the method currently being intercepted, `receiveAndExecute` returns a boolean which is what actually gets passed to the RepeatContext and is available inside the `RepeatOperations` class. I am a little but uncertain how the whole Repeat**** class package works so is there any simple way to implement such a functionality?

Comment: What, within Spring Batch, are you doing with the `RepeatOperations`?  Most use cases don't need to directly interact with it...

Comment: Besides a small change I am not doing very much at all other than using the original code. This is exactly what I mean, how is one supposed to handle triggering of some processing once the RepeatOperations class says that the context and policy are done? Should you register a listener? Even if that is the case I am still uncertain how to save and handle all collected messages contained within that transaction.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your configuration?

Comment: The example is right there in the link above. The spring setup can be found at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure-tests/src/test/resources/org/springframework/batch/jms/jms-context.xml except in my case I am not writing to a database but simply collecting the JMS messages to process them once the policy is done. I am not actually sure how the example above is working because should the transaction fail, he rolls back the database writes however all messages have already been acknowledged so they are lost.

Comment: In my case I am using a JMS transaction so that messages are left in the broker should an error occur. The issue then is figuring out how to store each incoming message within a transaction (only available inside the message listener) and process them once the policy is done while avoiding taking messages belonging to a different transaction which might be coming in while processing of the previous transaction is happening.

Comment: Are you using this within a Spring Batch step?  This is where I'm confused because SB handles the transaction boundaries for you...

Comment: I am not actually using with an integration project such as configuring a step and a job. Simply setting up a batchMessageListener as a bean in a webapp like the test setup has done which will listen to a queue and get messages from a broker batching the transaction. SB handles transaction boundaries yes but the issue is that the messages are contained within the MessageListener and I simply don't have access to information in there such as when the batch is done and has it gone ok or not

Comment: So the complications would be:

1 - Save the collected messages in memory until the batch is done, preferably in a thread-safe way
2 - Process the messages, after the batch is done but before the transaction is commited, since we want the processing of the collected batch to be part of the transaction so that if we have any issues with it, we can still rollback the transaction and not lose messages.

The issue implementing both is that, the way the spring project is done at least, is that where we have the messages available and where we have the "batch done" signaling have no connection.

Comment: @ByteFlinger, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @ByteFlinger : Have you got it working ? Did you write your own BatchMessageListenerContainer or there is something already existing in spring batch?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Most of the work can actually be found inside the spring-batch-infrastucture-tests. What I did was basically to overwrite some of the repeatOperations code with my own and then you can basically do what they did in the spring component. Look under the test folder, under resources to see the JMS context setup.

Comment: @ByteFlinger, How had you configured the container configuration? Is it possible to share your implementation? Im also in need of consuming multiple messages from Queue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55107244/hibernate-batch-to-insert-bulk-entities-from-queue-topic

Comment: Sadly I no longer work with the company I was working with when I wrote this question so I can't help with code and I haven't touched Java in quite a long time so I am afraid I can't be of much help